# Calling remote file (.bat) or start tomcat server from Android device

Tags: android

I want to develop one application by which I can **star, stop or restart the tomcat server remotely**.

Right now I can connect to the remote server using VPN. But is there any way to develop a android application and start a tomcat on remote machine?

Thanking you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to create a server application on the machine host witch you wish to start the tomcat, and create api between your android app and the server that will do what you are asking him too. VPN is example for such implementation if it's not enough create your own.(Not SVN but server ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use `ASP server`, so there is a `ASPX` webpage which I call,
which has the process to call the `*.bat` file.

```
//This code is on my ASP page load method
 Process p=Process.Start(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\DB.bat");
 Response.Write(p.StartTime.ToString());
```

Hope that gives you an idea